# jQuery-timepicker showing 12AM as PM

Tags: jquery

I am working with jQuery-timepicker, I have an issue.
When user navigates using hour it showing 12PM and not 12AM ?

Code I have tried,

```
$('#ftime').timepicker({
            timeFormat: "hh:mm TT",
            ampm: true,
            hourMin :4,
            hourMax : 24
});
```

Here is my try,

http://jsfiddle.net/o59eoomx/

Comment: Looks like a bug in jQuery-timepicker to me.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the plugin to the latest version?

Comment: sorry to hear you have a problem. but what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

To me, you are using different Library.

try:

```
$('#ftime').timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'h:i:s A' });
```

Link to the documentation, just make sure we are talking about the same [library](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/)